# How to change the style of "Contents" heading?

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, hyperref, titlesec, tocloft

Help me, please to make the style of "Contents" heading to be as `\chapter{Le choix du thème}`.

Also I would like to put all headings a little bit higher and to fix the `hyperref` for "Contents" in pdf

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} 

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage[no-sscript]{xltxtra}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguages{german,english,greek,polish,russian}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{CMU Serif}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tocloft}



\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek,Mapping=tex-text]{CMU Serif}
\newfontfamily\russianfont[Script=Cyrillic,Mapping=tex-text]{CMU Serif}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]% NEW
    {\Huge\bfseries\centering}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{5pt}{\Large}% NEW
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}% NEW
\titleformat{\section}
  {\bfseries}
  {\thesection}{1em}{}


\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\chaptername\newline}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{3.5cm}


\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}.}



\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose-ibid,citepages=suppress,sorting=nty,babel=other]{biblatex}

\renewcommand\mkbibnamelast[1]{\textsc{#1}}



\begin{document}

\doublespacing

\tableofcontents




\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Préface}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\protect\chaptername{Préface}}
\chapter{Le choix du thème}
Balah blah blah L'Organisation des Nations unies (ONU) 


\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Introduction}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\protect\chaptername{Introduction}}
\chapter{Initiatives du PO}
\section{Les lettres du PO 1904}
Balah blah blah (ONU) 



\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Chapitre}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\protect\chaptername{Chapitre}}
\chapter{Les décisions des CP}
\section{Les décisions des CP de Rhodes 1964}


\chapter{L'ouvre de la CIP}
\section{Les décisions de la I\textsuperscript{re} CPP}


\chapter{Évaluation de l'œuvre accomplie et perspectives}
\section{Évaluation de l'œuvre accomplie}


\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Conclusion}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\protect\chaptername{Conclusion}}
\chapter{}




\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc]
\printbibliography[keyword=primary,heading=subbibliography,title={Les sources principaux}]
\printbibliography[keyword=secondaire,heading=subbibliography,title={Les sources secondaires}]

\end{document}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please keep in mind to keep the example code [minimal](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), i.e. to strip all non-essential code from it. For example I couldn't compile it until a removed the font selection macros because I don't have the *CMU Serif* font installed.

Comment: What do you mean by "fix the `hyperref` for "Contents" in pdf"?

Comment: @N.N. I mean that after the compilation when I click to the first chapter in content of pdf file it sends me to Preface.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't provide a *mimimal* example, but by stripping down your code, I was at least able to fix the most serious problem, i.e. the ToC title not obeying the formatting of other chapter titles (e.g. not being centered). The reason for this is that by loading the `tocloft` package you disabled the influence of `titlesec` on the table of contents. Use the macros provided by `tocloft` instead. (I didn't bother to delve into your `hyperref` problems, as `hyperref` and `titlesec` also don't go together well.)

EDIT: `hyperref` problem solved. Your rather non-standard way of redefining `\thechapter` created two chapters numbered with `1` (although the number was hidden in case of the Introduction), and this confused `hyperref`. Solution: Set the `chapter` counter to `-1` before the Introduction, which will then become chapter 0.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\Huge\bfseries\centering}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{5pt}{\Large}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}
\titleformat{\section}
    {\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\chaptername\newline}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{3.5cm}

% These redefinitions were missing
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{30pt}
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{20pt}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\setcounter{chapter}{-1}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}.}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Introduction}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\protect\chaptername{Introduction}}
\chapter{Initiatives du PO}
\section{Les lettres du PO 1904}
Balah blah blah (ONU) 

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Chapitre}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\protect\chaptername{Chapitre}}
\chapter{Les décisions des CP}
\section{Les décisions des CP de Rhodes 1964}

\chapter{L'ouvre de la CIP}
\section{Les décisions de la I\textsuperscript{re} CPP}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Conclusion}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\protect\chaptername{Conclusion}}
\chapter{}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{A01} A bibitem.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @locstep Thank you. That is exactly I need.:)

Comment: @filokalos: No -- *now* it is exactly what you need. `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to redefine `\contentsname`. The `babel` package does this automatically for the selected language (for `latex`/`pdflatex`). The `polyglossia` package seems to do the same for XeLaTeX. Because this happens at the `\begin{document}` you need to redefine it afterwards. At best directly before it.

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Le choix du thème}
\tableofcontents
```

Comment: Thank you. But I mean to make the heading "Contents" which appears by `\tableofcontents` to look like `\chapter{Le choix du thème}`.

Comment: @filokalos: `\tableofcontents` should already use `\chapter*`. There should be no chapter number for the ToC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\renewcommand*\contentsname{new name}` like suggested in [a thread on LaTeX community](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=3053). Notice that the thread also recommends against that solution.

To turn the table of contents into a chapter use:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
        \chapter{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
        \@starttoc{toc}%
        }
\makeatother
```

I think there is a better solution though. This seems dirty.