# Changing the font size and position of glossaries title

Tags: glossaries

I'm using the `glossaries` package to generate a list of acronyms. I've changed the title of the page to **List of Abbreviations**, but this is appearing at the top center of the page, and its a little too small for my liking. How can I change this? I'd like it to be left aligned, like how the title appears for the **List of Tables** page.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{scalefnt} %Font size
\usepackage[top=1.0in,bottom=0.75in,left=1.25in,right=1in]{geometry} %Margins
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} % setting the spacing between lines
\usepackage{amsmath} %For math environment
\usepackage{graphicx} % For inserting pictures
\usepackage[font={large}]{caption} % Captions
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %Header and footer
\usepackage{subcaption} % for placing figures parallely
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=back,citecolor = black]{hyperref} %Creating links within the document
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{Figure \hspace{2mm}}   

\renewcommand*{\glossaryname}{List of Abbreviations}
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}
\renewcommand*{\glossaryentrynumbers}[1]{}


\newlength{\mylenf}
\settowidth{\mylenf}{\cftfigpresnum}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{\dimexpr\mylenf+2.0em}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\filright\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}
{20pt}{\LARGE\filcenter}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-30pt}{40pt}

\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}

 \makeglossaries
 \newacronym{irs}{IRS}{Internal Revenue Service}
 \newacronym{un}{UN}{United Nations}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\listoftables\thispagestyle{fancy}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
\addtocontents{lot}{~\hfill\textbf{Pg.No}\par} 
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations}
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{10}
\printglossary[type = acronym,title= List of Abbreviations]

\clearpage
\gls{irs} and \gls{un} are acronyms.
\end{document}
```

[image: What I'm getting]
[image: What I want]

Comment: Your example doesn't correspond to the attached pictures.

Comment: You need to post a real MWE; the code you posted doesn't show the undesired behaviour.

Comment: I've added the code to print the List of Tables, which was missing.

Comment: @user1556826 have you tried to compile the code you posted yourself? It does neither run without errors nor produce a layout anything near to the pictures you posted. Please post a real [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows us to reproduce your situation.

Comment: @cgnieder. Sorry for the poor MWE. I added all the packages I'm using, and the code is compiling now. Hopefully, it works out fine on your end too.

Comment: Related to your example the heading of of `listoffigure` is wrong. Try `chapter*` and you will see it. BTW: Your example is too long. There is no need for tikz or caption .... Please see: [How to change the style of “Contents” heading?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/how-to-change-the-style-of-contents-heading)

Comment: I guess the link was helpful. Then we can close this question as duplicated.